# Finding positive integers with the same digits

Tags: number-theory, problem-solving, prime-factorization

> Find the three smallest positive integers $K$ (two digits or greater) with the following properties:
>
> 1) $K=\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$ for some $n$
>
> 2) Each digit of $K$ is the same.

I was able to find the three $K's$ which are $55,66,666$ However, I am looking for a more systematic way. I was able to find the three numbers by testing $n$
I got the following:

For:

$55: n=10 $

$66: n=11 $

$666: n=36$

I am thinking about how can someone solve this problem without a calculator. I believe this problem is written to use a certain idea but I can't seem to find it. Does anyone see it?

As for my research, I've been reading about triangular numbers with the same digits. Someone suggested that I should $(n)$ and $(n+1)$ in prime factorization form.

I noticed that you can't get $6666$

If you try $n=115$, you get $6670$. So $6666$ is not possible.

So basically, I am looking for strategies in how to approach this problem. Any ideas?